# Xdotool action without focusing

Tags: xdotool, focus

Is there a way to automatically click at a specific place in specific window without getting the window focused?

Comment: Try the `-window` option for `mousemove` and `click`. `xwininfo -int -tree ..` may also be of interest.

Comment: @dirkt That does *not* prevent the window from getting focus, at least in Unity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just been struggling with the same problem and this is the best option I could come up with:

```
$ (w=`xdotool getactivewindow` && xdotool click 1 && xdotool windowactivate $w)
```

This line saves the ID of the currently active window, then issues the `click` command at the location of the mouse cursor, and then forces the focus to go back to the window that was active.

Thus, the target window WILL gain focus for a split second, but then the focus will return to the original window.

This is suboptimal, but may be an acceptable solution depending on what you are doing.